# How to properly inherit from dataclass with base instance re-usage

Tags: python, class, polymorphism, python-dataclasses

Consider the following:

```py
@dataclass
class Base:
  prop1: str
  prop2: str


@dataclass
class Derived1(Base):
  isValid: bool = self.prop2.casefold() == 'valid'

@dataclass
class Derived2(Base):
  isOpen: bool = self.prop1.casefold() == 'open'
  isShared :bool
```

In this particular example, baseclass it just 2 props, but imagine it is 773 props just for argument sake.
Something, somewhere, you dont care what and where, returns you an instance of `Base`. Now, you may want to promote it to `Derived1`, keeping all the existing values. Normally, as far as I know, if I want to an instance of a `Derived1` or `Derived2` class id have to initialize this instance and then manually write assigned in Derived's `__init__` or `__post_init__` for all the 773 props. It is madness. After some re-search I found a great suggestion that solves this. Instead I use normal class and update props from existing base instance via `__dict__` trick:

```py
class Derived(Base):
    isOpen: bool = False

    def __init__(self, base: Base):
        self.__dict__.update(base.__dict__)
        self.isOpen = (str(base.currStatus).casefold() == 'open')
```

While this seems to be working just fine I keep getting a hard error from `pylint` that there needs to be super. And this is what I'm confused about - do I need need a super here? The issue is that with `super` I'm back to square one where I have to re-init all 700+ props manually... which is what I wanted to avoid in a first place.

This whole thing seems incredibly silly - this is python we are talking about, I easily can see it having this problem when it comes to classes (which some other languages solved 30 years ago).

Comment: `super().__init__(**base.__dict__)` instead of `self.__dict__.update(base.__dict__)`. `@dataclass` generates `__init__` with args and kwargs similar to dataclass structure (that's why fields without default values go first in dataclasses). `**base.__dict__` will unwrap `Base` object fields to kwargs and pass them to superclass `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks! Should my derived class me annotated with `@dataclass` decorator in this case or it is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Use `asdict` and include the requirements for dictionary unpacking. The below mixin already has this ability, and a little more.

```py
# mixins.py
from __future__  import annotations
from dataclasses import asdict
from typing      import Any, Iterable
import json


""" Dataclass_mi: dataclass mixin for dictionary behavior
  supports:
    *) .keys(), .values(), .items()
    *) dictionary unpacking
    *) pretty-print self as json
    *) return self as dict
    *) reassign any/all fields in one call
      +) optional __post_init__ call after reassignment
"""
class Dataclass_mi:
  @property
  def asdict(self) -> dict:
    return asdict(self)
    
  def items(self) -> Iterable:
    return asdict(self).items()
    
  def values(self) -> Iterable:
    return asdict(self).values()
      
  # required for dictionary unpacking
  def keys(self) -> Iterable:
    return asdict(self).keys()
  
  # required for dictionary unpacking  
  # an error will be raised if this key does not exist
  def __getitem__(self, key:str) -> Any:
    return getattr(self, key)
  
  # pretty-print self as json
  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return json.dumps(asdict(self), indent=4, default=str)
  
  # reassign fields from kwargs and optionally call __post_init__
  def __call__(self, initvars:dict|None=None, **kwargs) -> Dataclass_mi:
    # if key exists, set value. otherwise, ignore.
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
      if hasattr(self, key):
        setattr(self, key, value)
        
    # if you want __post_init__ to be called, but it doesn't accept arguments -
    # pass initvars as an empty dict
    if initvars is not None: 
      self.__post_init__(**initvars)
        
    # let this be an inline method        
    return self
```

###### classes

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from mixins import Dataclass_mi
   
@dataclass
class Base(Dataclass_mi):
  prop1: str
  prop2: str


@dataclass
class Derived1(Base):
  isValid: bool = False

  def __post_init__(self) -> None:
    self.isValid = self.prop2.lower() == 'valid'


@dataclass
class Derived2(Base):
  isShared: bool 
  isOpen  : bool = False
  
  def __post_init__(self) -> None:
    self.isOpen = self.prop1.lower() == 'open'
```

###### usage

```py
base = Base('open', 'valid')

# init
derived = Derived2(**base, isShared=False)

print(derived)

# customize
derived({}, prop1='closed')

print(derived)
```

###### output

```json
{
    "prop1": "open",
    "prop2": "valid",
    "isShared": false,
    "isOpen": true
}
{
    "prop1": "closed",
    "prop2": "valid",
    "isShared": false,
    "isOpen": false
}
```